# Как переделать кастомный select не по клику, а по наведению?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Написал кастомный select, но он работает по клику. Как можно сделать выпадающее меню по наведению?

```js
let lang = () => {
    let langCurrent = document.querySelectorAll('.lang__header'),
          langtItem = document.querySelectorAll('.lang__item'),
    langCurrentText = document.querySelectorAll('.lang__current');

    langCurrentText.forEach(el => {
        let text = el.innerHTML;

        if (el.innerHTML.length > 3) {
            text = text.substr(0, 3);
            el.innerHTML = text;
        }
    });

    langCurrent.forEach((item) => {
        item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            e.currentTarget.parentElement.classList.toggle('lang--opened');
        })
    });

    langtItem.forEach((item) => {
        item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            e.currentTarget.closest('.lang').querySelector('.lang__current').innerHTML = e.currentTarget.innerHTML.slice(0, 3);
            e.currentTarget.closest('.lang').classList.remove('lang--opened');
        })
    });
};

lang();
```

```css
.lang {
     position: relative;
}
 .lang:hover .lang__current {
     color: red;
}
 .lang:hover .lang__arrow {
     fill: red;
}
 .lang--opened .lang__body {
     display: block;
}
 .lang__header {
     display: -webkit-flex;
     display: -ms-flex;
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     cursor: pointer;
}
 .lang__body {
     display: none;
     left: 0;
     position: absolute;
     top: 100%;
     right: 0;
     box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
     border-radius: 6px;
     background-color: #fff;
     color: #000;
     min-width: 172px;
     max-width: 300px;
     padding: 8px 0;
}
 .lang__item {
     cursor: pointer;
     padding: 10px 12px;
     line-height: 1;
     transition: 0.2s;
}
 .lang__current {
     font-family: "SourceSansPro-SemiBold", sans-serif;
     display: block;
     margin-right: 7px;
     font-size: 14px;
     transition: 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="lang">
  <div class="lang__header"><span class="lang__current">Українська мова</span></div>
  <div class="lang__body">
    <div class="lang__item">Українська мова</div>
    <div class="lang__item">Русский язык</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас прописан click, достаточно изменить название события на hover
Замените:

```
langCurrent.forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        e.currentTarget.parentElement.classList.toggle('lang--opened');
    })
});
```

на это

```
 langCurrent.forEach((item) => {
        item.addEventListener('hover', (e) => {
            e.currentTarget.parentElement.classList.toggle('lang--opened');
        })
    });
```

Comment: Это не работает, проверьте пожалуйста

Comment: Если не работает hover, замените его на mouseenter

Comment: mouseenter не реагирует на то, когда курсор увели от элемента, он реагирует на повторное наведение

Comment: Ну а как вы хотели ? Вы задали вопрос как сделать что бы открывалось при наведении, что было и сделано.

Comment: имелся в виду hover

Comment: @fenq27, а как по вашему работает hover? Это как раз таки `mouseenter` (когда курсор попал на элемент) и `mouseleave` (когда курсор ушёл с элемента). Логично можно предположить, что при `mouseenter` мы сделаем `.classList.add('lang--opened')`, а при `mouseleave` - `.classList.remove('lang--opened')` и всё.

Comment: Делал так, но тогда по клику на элемент дропдауна перестаёт работать его закрытие, а именно вот эта строка: e.currentTarget.closest('.lang').classList.remove('lang--opened');